# Excel Macro saving as CSV to shared drive with corey-1, corey-2, etc

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to set up a macro to save a file in a sequence to a shared drive at work.  The name needs to be the same so I am looking to have it set up to save as coreyk-1, coreyk-2, coreyk-3 etc.  I can't have them overwrite and I am wondering if its possible to have a macro sequence like above?

I have gotten it to the point where it will save, but will only over-write files of the same name.

Answer (score 0):

How is something like this - note: change the "noFiles" to the number of total files you want.  Also, naturally edit the file path (make sure it ends with a "\" or it won't save).

```
Sub save()
    Dim filePath As String, theFileName As String, noFiles As Integer, i As Integer
    noFiles = 5
    filePath = "C:\Users\USERNAME\Documents\MyFolder\"
    theFileName = "coreyk-"


    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    For i = 1 To noFiles
         ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FILENAME:=filePath & theFileName & i & ".xls",  FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
    Next i

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```